# Populate Textboxes by Clicking a Table in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

Populate Textboxes by Clicking a Table in MVC. The Javascript code which I am using doesn't change the text boxes values when I select another row on the table.

Does anyone have an idea please help?

Answer (score 0):

I have the Answer to My own question, so any one who needs it. just say the word and I'll type the problem is am using a phone right now